# Custom login screen with Auth0 and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, auth0

Angular 2 has a custom login: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/02-custom-login

But I can't find any for AngularJS, https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs

Is it not possible to have a custom login with AngularJS? Or do I need to manually use an API on the back-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to achieve the same functionality either by using Angular 1.X or Angular2. In this case, it's just a mismatch in the available sample code.

You would do this using the same Auth0 library, [Auth0.js](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js), that is being used in the Angular2 sample to achieve the custom login, so you can use that code as a baseline of what you need to do and adapt it from Angular2 to Angular 1.X or you can also check the documentation of the Auth0.js library itself; the [section about single page apps](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js#single-page-apps) would likely be the most useful.